# Union of two connected sets in a particular case

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

In a previous exam on metric topology: We are given two connected sets $A$ and $B$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ with $A \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$. We are asked to prove that $A \cup B$ is connected. Before that we were asked to prove that if $x \in A \cap cl(B)$, then $B \cup ${$x$} is connected. Then deduce the desired result.

The first step I was able to prove by noting that this set is included between $B$ and its closure and thus it is connected since $B$ itself is connected. For the deduction I first deduced that $B \cup (A \cap cl(B))$ is connected since it is the union of joint connected sets. Trying to use this fact I wrote $A \cup B= [B \cup (A \cap cl(B))] \cup [B \cup (A \cap int(B^c)]$. I didn't know how to proceed further. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you are given that $A \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$. So there is an $x \in A\cap cl(B)$. Then $A\cup B = A \cup (B \cup \{x\})$, a union of two sets that are not disjoint and are both connected (by the earlier exercise in the case of $B \cup \{x\}$) and, as you know, such a union is connected. In your proof attempt, you made things too hard by considering all of $cl(B)$ not just a subset of it that meets $A$. Consider an example like the intervals $A = [0, 1]$ and $B = [1, 2)$  in the real line to see where your argument breaks down.